# Sleeping causes increased UDP send/recv latency

Tags: linux, macos, network-programming, udp, latency

I am experimenting with UDP loopback performance, and I discovered that sleeping my thread causes a large spike in minimum UDP latency.  I have written approximately the same code in C and Rust to spin up two threads in the same process, send/receive UDP packets, and measure how long the `send` and `recv` calls take.  I have run my experiments on both macOS and Linux.

What I have found is that using `sleep()` within the loop to throttle down the call/response loop a bit actually causes the `recv()` and `send()` calls to take much longer than they usually do.  [My full code is available as a gist](https://gist.github.com/staticfloat/fbe63faf52968a7e00378db12293247e), but I'll include the relevant loop in the client here:

```
while (1) {
    // This sleep causes a large increase in latency
#ifdef ENABLE_SLEEP
    usleep(10000);
#endif

    double t_pre_send = curr_timestamp();
    if (send(sockfd, NULL, 0, 0) == -1) {
        perror("send failed");
    }
    avg_send_elapsed = 0.9*avg_send_elapsed + 0.1*(curr_timestamp() - t_pre_send);

    double t_pre_recv = curr_timestamp();
    socklen_t len = 0;
    int num_bytes = recvfrom(sockfd, (char *)buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, &len);
    avg_recv_elapsed = 0.9*avg_recv_elapsed + 0.1*(curr_timestamp() - t_pre_recv);

    double curr_time = curr_timestamp();
    if (curr_time - last_print > 1.0) {
        last_print = curr_time;
        printf("[%.1f] send: %.2fus\trecv: %.2fus\n", curr_time - t_start, avg_send_elapsed*1000000, avg_recv_elapsed*1000000);
    }
}
```

The results look something like this without a sleep:

```
[1.0] send: 4.93us      recv: 7.41us
[2.0] send: 4.68us      recv: 7.04us
[3.0] send: 4.86us      recv: 7.58us
[4.0] send: 4.79us      recv: 7.60us
[5.0] send: 4.88us      recv: 7.03us
[6.0] send: 4.70us      recv: 7.57us
[7.0] send: 4.49us      recv: 8.02us
[8.0] send: 4.47us      recv: 7.23us
[9.0] send: 4.58us      recv: 7.15us
```

And something like this with a sleep:

```
[1.0] send: 23.85us     recv: 102.13us
[2.0] send: 35.41us     recv: 78.07us
[3.0] send: 70.47us     recv: 141.07us
[4.0] send: 29.90us     recv: 107.35us
[5.0] send: 45.17us     recv: 194.27us
[6.0] send: 32.49us     recv: 117.74us
[7.0] send: 32.25us     recv: 117.83us
[8.0] send: 35.48us     recv: 85.67us
[9.1] send: 33.86us     recv: 108.71us
```

I would expect the sleep to adjust the number of loop iterations we perform per second, but I would not expect it to impact how long it takes to run the `send()` and `recvfrom()` function calls.  Does anyone have an explanation for why my UDP latency increases so drastically, and is there a technique I can use to throttle my transmissions without incurring this latency penalty?

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with you in embedded system. In my case, usleep(10) + sendto() takes about 80us within some variation. It is dramatically reduced when I set scheduling policy and priority of sending/receiving thread.

```
pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&pthread_attr, SCHED_FIFO);
struct sched_param sched;
sched.sched_priority = sched_get_priority_max(SCHED_FIFO);  // The highest priority
pthread_attr_setschedparam(&pthread_attr, &sched);
```

BTW, your usleep(10000) will make your thread to sleep 10ms, not 10us. I hope your results attached have typos in unit.